# Does it stay this fun?

Tags: business, career, reel

I'm really just starting out in the world of Sound Design and I'm having a blast so far. I worked on a web series (for free, of course) and it turned out to be quite demanding as far as sound goes. I captured/mixed the dialogue and recorded most of the material I used for sound effects. The music was stock. I just did my first paid work, and I want to keep going. Is this most likely going to be a soul-crushing experience, or does it just get better? Where are you on the road to sound nirvana? Here's a [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShwIWW4g3ck&feature=plcp) to one of the episodes I worked on. Thanks for the inspiration (also helpful feedback).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Reed, welcome to SSD. Glad to hear that you're having fun so far! Here's the good news: It only gets better.

If your journey is anything like what most of us have experienced, you will have your share of ups and downs and will most likely question why in the world you didn't take that job at your father's hardware store. But persevere through those bad times, set your sights high and jump to the next rung when presented with the opportunity.

Having clear goals is paramount; without them and you could end up mired in the same old job you started in, always longing for that big break that never comes. And when the door opens to your goal, **don't hesitate**. Go for it, and tell everyone why you're going for it. They will (hopefully) respect you for it, encourage you and send you along with best wishes, leaving you with strong bridges in your wake rather than burning ones. Remember, the "sound design" community tends to be very small and word travels fast, whether good or bad.

Best wishes for your career!

Comment: Thanks, Jay. As you can tell, I'm pretty excited about all of this. And thanks to whoever created and organizes this site. What a great resource; one that I'll definitely be using!

Comment: Jay, that is one of the best summations of this crazy, fun, stressful, joyous, exhausting profession!

Comment: When you DO have "one of those days" (and you will, young Jedi, you will), then also check out this thread at Gearslutz http://www.gearslutz.com/board/post-production-forum/612830-bad-day-post-better-than.html. Always helps to put things in perspective